# Can anyone help me add a link / button to a document library webpart / page

Tags: sharepoint

I've created a custom content type .. based on a folder .. with some added fields ...

I can add the content type to the page.. however when you click the (+) new doc .. it only brings up the upload document dialog .. and not the option to create my custom folder ... so .. I thought how do I add a button / link to the web part page .. that the user can click instead of having to go up to file .. new .. then click on my custom content type:folder ..

this is driving me nutz! it seems like it should be a lot easier to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Content Editer WebPart". This link might help you.
[Content Editer Webpart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-foundation-help/using-the-content-editor-web-part-HA101794745.aspx)